# How to List the Sum of a Number of Values in an Array for a Number of Times and Find the Most Common Output?

Tags: arrays, math

I have 6 different numbers, and I have 5 of them each. I have to pick 5 numbers randomly out of these 30 numbers (without repetition). The code I am looking for finds the most frequent sum value out of the 17.100.720 possibilities I have as P(30,5) = 17.100.720.

How would I write a function that lists all of the sum possibilities and returns the value that is encountered the most often (I don't need to see the list of sums, all I need is the value I am looking for)?

The language it is written in does not matter, though I'd prefer being able to run it online.

With the Javascript knowledge I have already, I can only pick 5 numbers randomly from the 30 numbers, remove the number picked from the array, take their sum, reset the array, and repeat this process for 17.100.720 times.

Comment: What if two sums are equally frequent? (That is certain to happen.)

Comment: It could list sums that occur more than thrice. There must be one particular sum that occurs the most often. @Beta

Comment: Can we assume that the six numbers are such that no collisions are possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, you can solve it using dynamic programming.

Make 2D table of size `6 x Maxsum`.

Cell `A[k][s]` will contain a number of variants to get sum `s` with `k` summands from your list.

Fill the first cell `A[0][0] = 1`

The fill the table for every value `v in list`

```
if (A[k-1][s-v] > 0)
     A[k][s] = A[k-1][s-v] + 1
```

Note that walking through the table should go from the end to start to avoid double counting of the same item.

At the end check the maxumum counter in 5-th line of table

If `MaxSum` is too big, table size might be too large - in this case it is worth to use map instead of 2D array. In this case one might prefer to keep two maps - before current item and after adding current item and use the seond one at the next step.